# how to generate numbers from 1-99(max) and add it to date eg 030317-001 the auto generated numbers change with every different date

Tags: php, html

this code generates numbers like 030317-001 to 030317-010 in a list. how do i use it to generate the same sequence in 1 button without repeat for a maximum of e.g. 030317-099?

```
<?php
    $x = date("dmy");//the value of x is today's date
     //the logic 
    function add_nol($number,$add_nol) {
       while (strlen($number)<$add_nol) {
           $number = "0".$number;
       }
       return $number;
    }

    //usage..It gives 
    for($y=1;$y<=10;$y++){
        echo $x."-".add_nol($y,3)."<br />";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Ummm... change 10 to 99?

Comment: have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php. The part with the leading 0 is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The code is simply showing iterations of the loop. It calls a function `_add_nol($y, 3)` where parameters are:

`$y` - an integer generated by the `for` loop

`3`  - a number of digits padded by zeros you require in the second part of the number (after the dash "-")

The following will work for you:

```
<?php
    $x = date("dmy");//the value of x is today's date

    //the logic 
    function add_nol($number,$add_nol) {
        while (strlen($number)<$add_nol) {
            $number = "0".$number;
        }
        return $number;
    }

    // new usage
    for($y=1;$y<=99;$y++){
        echo $x."-".add_nol($y,3)."<br />";
    }
?>
```